# How to change an ionic3 page attribute within a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to change the value of a given attribute after a few seconds, but using the setTimeout it is not possible to change the class attribute.

```
    let answer =  document.getElementById(id);

    answer.style.background = "#00a232";
    this.activated = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      answer.style.background = "#97a8c6";
      //this.activated = false

    }, 1500);
```

I commented the line of the attribute change, because it does not work because it is a function and does not have such an attribute in it.

I tried to pass a class method to make this change with:

```
let answer =  document.getElementById(id);

answer.style.background = "#00a232";
this.activated = true;
setTimeout(this.activate, 1500);
```

With the written method as follows:

```
activate(answer){
  answer.style.background = "#97a8c6";
  this.activated = false
}
```

However I can not pass parameters, and also the attribute is not modified if the method is called by setTimeout().

How to modify the class attribute after the setTimeout () time passage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is scoping.

Have you tried using fat arrow notation? That changes the scope of `this`.

You have:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  answer.style.background = "#97a8c6";
  this.activated = false // this is in the scope of the function

}, 1500);
```

Have you tried:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  answer.style.background = "#97a8c6";
  this.activated = false // this is in the same scope where the function was created

}, 1500);
```

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html): Arrow functions capture the `this` where the function is created rather than where it is invoked